# String Trimming Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following string `"survey_questions_attributes_1392746726560_question_title"` I need to trim all the strings starting from the first character till the first number. How to do that?

Comment: Please let us see what you have attempted.

Comment: I'd start with looking at the documentation for `String` and seeing what's in the toolbox: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html

Answer (score 4):

[String#slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-slice) method supports regex,so you can do:

```
[67] pry(main)> "survey_questions_attributes_1392746726560_question_title"[/\d.*/]
=> "1392746726560_question_title"
```

Comment: OP want to **trim all the strings starting from the first character till the first number**.. But you didn't do that..

Comment: @ArupRakshit if you can get the same result without mutating the object, I think I would go for the option that does not mutate the object

Comment: Humm, But I followed OP :-) .. Didn't think that much..

Answer (score 1):

```
"survey_questions_attributes_1392746726560_question_title".sub /\D*/,''
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do using [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

```
s = "survey_questions_attributes_1392746726560_question_title"
s[/[a-z_]+(?:\d)/] = ""
s # => "1392746726560_question_title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Behold the power of [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and bask in it's glory.

```
string =  "survey_questions_attributes_223233333_question_title"
puts string.sub( string.scan(/survey_questions_attributes_(.*)/)[0][0] , " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"survey_questions_attributes_1392746726560_question_title".split(/\D+/, 2).last
# => "1392746726560_question_title"
```